# AWS Polly reads word 're-record' as 're minus record'

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I'm using AWS Polly in my Android app. I'm pretty sure that it was reading correctly `re-record` before.

Idk what's changed but Polly reads it as "re minus record". Is there a way to exclude this issue by using SSML tags?

I tried with different voice types (male and female), but no luck.

```
private fun getSignedUrl(text: String, speechRate: Int): String {
    // Create speech synthesis request.
    val synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest = SynthesizeSpeechPresignRequest()
        .withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3)
        .withText("<speak><prosody rate=\"${speechRate}%\">$text</prosody></speak>")
        .withTextType("ssml") //https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html
        .withVoiceId(voices[speechGender].id)
        .withEngine(Engine.Neural)
        .withLexiconNames("globalenglish"))

    return client?.getPresignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl(synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest)?.toString()?:""
}
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I’ve just tested on the console here: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech?region=eu-central-1

It's broken only if you activate lexicon as globalenglish.

[image]

Comment: Do the same input params work correctly in the console (Polly > Text-to-Speech) for you?  I can't reproduce this in the console, nor in an app that uses the Polly API (I don't have source for that app though).

Comment: My dictionary shows the word as `rerecord`, rather than being hyphenated. So, perhaps Polly knows that it's not a single word and synthesises it accordingly. Can you change the source material?

Comment: I’ve just tested on the console here: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech?region=eu-central-1

it reads correctly if you type “re-record” if you don’t apply lexicon.

But when you activate the lexicon English, it reads like “re minus record”. 
I’ve updated my answer above.
I’ve also checked Oxford Dictionary how to write “re-record”
https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=re-record

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was working correctly a few months ago. We have a string that asks users if they want to re-record any voice messages. So something has changed dynamically with the English lexicon

Comment: Ah, this lexicons are provided by us! I'll check with our Data team :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the Lexicon that's used. Without using lexicons, it works perfectly splendid!